# Using exec in php for setting system clock

Tags: php, exec, sudo

I am using a php script which takes a timestamp value from browser and tries to set the system clock. i m using mamp box in my mac mini. how do i set the mac mini system clock through php script.

I tried using shell_exec, exec, system for achieving this , but it doesn't work.

Example, my php script looks something like this,

```
<?

$timestamp = $_GET['timestamp'];

exec('date '.$timestamp);

?>
```

When i try the same date set command in terminal i see the clock changing. ( sudo date timestamp ), but i dont know how to achieve it through php script executing a privileged command. Kindly help.

Thanks,
Srini.

Comment: Also I had used the php date/time set to set time, although i dont get error message, there is no difference in the system clock. kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Changing the system time is usually restricted to root-level accounts. PHP will be running under the user id of the webserver, which SHOULD NOT BE root. You'll have to use `sudo` to let the webserver run with elevated privileges for this purpose.

However, why do you need to set timestamps like this? You're basically passing some random data passed in on a url to a shell command. What's to stop someone submitting

```
  http://example.com?timestamp=; rm -rf /
```

and nuking every file on your server that the webserver has access to?

If you're trying to sync times between servers, then use [ntp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), which is designed for clock synching.

Comment: I am just testing a framework . This is just an example. But I generally wanted to know whats the idea behind executing privileged commands from http.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do sanitize your input. In this case, sanitize $_GET['timestamp']. Make sure it is in the format `date` will understand. Make sure it is using [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

You can use `exec('sudo date '.escapeshellarg($timestamp));`. But make sure your Apache user has right to sudo without passwords. You can specify in `/etc/sudoers` to allow ONLY date command to be executed by root. It is safier.

Another option is to create your own shell script and allow to sudo only your script.

Comment: How to do i allow the date command to be executed without password. can you explain me more on that

Comment: can you explain how to achieve the solution using /etc/sudoers in detail.   Thanks

Comment: Suposing your apache runs with user www-data, you could use `www-data LOCAL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/date` you can read more at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers OBS: I did not test the line in my sudoers