# PHP Change Server Date & Time

Tags: php, exec

How do I change the server time using PHP? From my research so far, I found you can execute any terminal line with the function `exec()`. What do I put into that function to say change the date and time to November 24, 2013 12:38?

The reason I must do this in PHP is I do not have access to the physical server, so everything must be done remotely. I have set up Cron Jobs before using `exec()`, so I should have permission to change the date as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the server is running on windows I believe you could do `exec('time 12:38:00 PM')` and `exec('date 11/24/2013')`. If it is a linux based server I think you can do something like this: `exec('date -s "24 NOV 2013 12:38:00"')`. Also you might want to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958972/using-exec-in-php-for-setting-system-clock). I realize it isn't the same but the person who answered brought up a good point about not running php as root in linux, assuming you are doing so.

I used [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/) link for linux and this [one](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Computer-Time-and-Date-Using-the-Command-Prompt) for windows.