# Change server time using PHP

Tags: php

How can I change the date and time of the server using PHP scripts? I know it will work if you change the time in the CLI but is it possible to change programatically?

I have created a route to that will pass a date and time `localhost/date/{date}/time/{time}` to test if it will work when I will call the `date()` in my controller.

Does someone know any method that can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Change Server Date & Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177595/php-change-server-date-time)

Comment: Also see: [Using exec in php for setting system clock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958972/using-exec-in-php-for-setting-system-clock)

Comment: you want to permanently change server data? or you are having time zone problem?

Comment: this is most likely a real bad idea, a lot of things you probably haven't thought about expect the time to be correct and not change unexpectedly

Comment: The more you can find with [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: @nogad yes it is a bad idea, but I just want to change time so that I can check my API if it is working. I know it can be done by changing the time in the server manually but I want to try changing it using php scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Do exec('time 12:38:00 PM') and exec('date 11/24/2013') if on Windows. Credit to Dan for this answer.

This question's also a possible duplicate of [PHP Change Server Date & Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177595/php-change-server-date-time).

Comment: It's your responsibility to put that you tried this in the question in that case and not to just downvote things.

Answer (score -1):

If you can do it in command line.. then you can do it in PHP too...

All you have to do is use [PHP's shell_exec() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Try it.